# wordpress plug-in or anything that will allow us to edit the meta tags for each individual post?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, post, seo

I researched at google but couldnot find anything.

**Is there a plug-in or anything that will allow us to edit the meta tags for each individual post?**

Appreciate helps! thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also work with the meta description field in pages, single posts and post categories without a plugin by using a custom field called "description" and the built in category descriptions:

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php if (is_page()) { echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'description', true);

} elseif (is_category()) { echo trim(strip_tags(category_description()));

} elseif (is_single()) { echo $title = get_the_title();

} else { echo bloginfo('description'); } ?>" />
```

Adapted from [Stupid WordPress Tricks • Perishable Press](http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/12/01/stupid-wordpress-tricks/#swt_22)

Comment: haha, I've thought same solution :D just completed ;) thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there are ; for instance, if you search for ["meta tags" in wordpress' plugin lists](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=meta+tags&sort=popular), you'll get a few answers.

One of those answers is [All in One SEO Pack](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/) -- which has good ratings, seems to work with recent versions of Wordpress, and has been recently updated.

Amongst the features, you'll see *(quoting)* :

- Generates META tags automatically
- You can override any title and set any META description and any META keywords you want.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use the excerpt field as the meta description if the page is a single post & the excerpt contains some text. Code for header.php:

```
<?php
if (is_single() && $post->post_excerpt != “”) {
$post = $wp_query->post;
$descrip = strip_tags($post->post_excerpt);
echo ‘<meta name=”description” content=”‘.$descrip.’”>’;
}
?>
```

I detailed the technique in [this blog post](http://blog.deepcognition.com/description-meta-tag-in-wordpress).